# How to grade a test with different points by answer in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

I'm trying to do something similar than this: https://exceljet.net/formula/score-quiz-answers-with-key

But it is not the same because I have different "points" for each question.

For example, correct answer for question 1 gives you 2 points, but correct answer for question 10 gives you 6 points.

I need to get the total of points for each student based on their answers and how many points each answer gives them.

This is the sheet with the answers and points:

[image: This is the sheet with the answers of]

Comment: Use SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: @BigBen Not fair. Your suggestion is already in the question's tags. I think you should work out the formula as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this formula. Paste to R5 (first result row) and copy down.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B5:Q5=B$1:Q$1),B$3:Q$3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest to add more cells to calculate how many points each student got for each question. Then you can sum those up and divide by the total.

[Here's an example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JOMwIFQDPMrCFopy7fQGqZNkcAnveIaa2s0PtfMRgvs/edit?usp=sharing)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Pzl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on below formula.

```
=SUM((B5:Q5=$B$1:$Q$1)*($B$2:$Q$2))
```

Matrix multiplication will also give you desired result.

```
=MMULT(--(B5:Q5=$B$1:$Q$1),TRANSPOSE($B$2:$Q$2))
```